Unusual Wallet Connect SessionRequest from Safe{Wallet} Web Interface
When connected via Wallet Connect to the Safe App (i.e. I want to interact with my Safe from the Wallet Interface and connected to an external wallet via wallet connect).
Any attempt to prepare, say ownership removal or addition, transactions is resulting in unexpected Session Request:
For example, an removeOwner transaction whose call data (expressed as a MetaTransaction would be):
{
    to: '0x7fa8e8264985C7525Fc50F98aC1A9b3765405489',
    value: '0',
    data: '0xf8dc5dd900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000007f01d9b227593e033bf8d6fc86e634d27aa855680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
}

But when building the equivalent transaction results in the following WalletKit.SessionRequest (notice how the callData is much longer and only includes the shorter as a subset):
{
  "id": 1729936486565256,
  "topic": "7d4d4cb349578d698b9f2776e0b5dfb8e143c0111fdaf013515e5f99336ede3b",
  "params": {
    "request": {
      "method": "eth_sendTransaction",
      "params": [
        {
          "gas": "0x16790",
          "maxFeePerGas": "0x39e9ec55",
          "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0xfc363",
          "nonce": "0x29",
          "from": "0x102543f7e6b5786a444cc89ff73012825d13000d",
          "to": "0x7fa8e8264985c7525fc50f98ac1a9b3765405489",
          "data": "0x6a7612020000000000000000000000007fa8e8264985c7525fc50f98ac1a9b37654054890000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064f8dc5dd900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000007f01d9b227593e033bf8d6fc86e634d27aa855680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041000000000000000000000000102543f7e6b5786a444cc89ff73012825d13000d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
      ],
      "expiryTimestamp": 1729936786
    },
    "chainId": "eip155:11155111"
  },
  "verifyContext": {
    "verified": {
      "verifyUrl": "https://verify.walletconnect.org",
      "validation": "UNKNOWN",
      "origin": "https://app.safe.global"
    }
  }
}

The question is, what is all this additional call data in the Session Request? The Safe message request actually appears to contain the correct call data:
{
  "id": 1729936498322140,
  "topic": "7d4d4cb349578d698b9f2776e0b5dfb8e143c0111fdaf013515e5f99336ede3b",
  "params": {
    "request": {
      "method": "eth_signTypedData_v4",
      "params": [
        "0x102543f7e6b5786a444cc89ff73012825d13000d",
        "{\"types\":{\"SafeTx\":[{\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"data\",\"type\":\"bytes\"},{\"name\":\"operation\",\"type\":\"uint8\"},{\"name\":\"safeTxGas\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"baseGas\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"gasPrice\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"gasToken\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"refundReceiver\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"nonce\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"EIP712Domain\":[{\"name\":\"chainId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"verifyingContract\",\"type\":\"address\"}]},\"domain\":{\"chainId\":\"0xaa36a7\",\"verifyingContract\":\"0x7fa8e8264985c7525fc50f98ac1a9b3765405489\"},\"primaryType\":\"SafeTx\",\"message\":{\"to\":\"0x7fa8e8264985c7525fc50f98ac1a9b3765405489\",\"value\":\"0\",\"data\":\"0xf8dc5dd900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000007f01d9b227593e033bf8d6fc86e634d27aa855680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001\",\"operation\":\"0\",\"safeTxGas\":\"0\",\"baseGas\":\"0\",\"gasPrice\":\"0\",\"gasToken\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",\"refundReceiver\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",\"nonce\":\"0\"}}"
      ],
      "expiryTimestamp": 1729936798
    },
    "chainId": "eip155:11155111"
  },
  "verifyContext": {
    "verified": {
      "verifyUrl": "https://verify.walletconnect.org",
      "validation": "UNKNOWN",
      "origin": "https://app.safe.global"
    }
  }
}

Furthermore, I wouldn't have ever noticed this if the sendTransaction request werent failing pm_sponsorUserOperation (simulation) with a cryptic error:
Details: UserOperation reverted during simulation with reason: 0xacfdb444
My best guess here is that the interface has determined this safe as having some "exotic" modules installed and wants to wrap the transaction into a module execution... Or maybe its encoding an execTransaction call...
I also attempted to bypass the Sponsorship Simulation, but executing the transaction without a paymaster. It went through, but still reverted on the actual function call:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x65554bdcfae6101dae98a8690da61a17ead638dd4c08d05e4b2b24655d898c53
Simulating this failed transaction shows that it was indeed a module execution that failed! It seems that the Safe Wallet Web Interface is misinterpreting how the eth_sendTransaction should be encoded.

Thank you for your great question. Since we contacted you directly, can you kindly mark this as answered?
For the record, this was internal feedback:
"It's kind of using Safe Wallet as an encoding tx utility. But users could already sign those Safe Transactions in the Safe Wallet interface. If he then decodes, encodes again as USerOp, signs again, and executes the user op, those remaining potentially signed Safe Transactions remain executable, meaning it would open up replay attacks."
So, while this case is unblocked, we don't recommend using Safe Wallet this way.

Yes thanks for your response. I will also try to come back here and provide a more lengthy description of a solution, workaround and other considerations. If I do get around to that we could consider it the "answer".
